# PDF stamp with angle using cli

Tags: pdf

I use something like:

```
pdftk in.pdf multistamp watermark.pdf output out.pdf
```

to add watermarks to PDFs.

The `watermark.pdf` I usually create in Inkscape.

This is somewhat cumbersome, especially as I usually simply create a one word watermark across a single page with a set opacity. I.e:

```
+---------------------------+
|                           |
|  |
+----------------------------+
```

Is there a ***simple*** way to do this with some command line tool?

For example:

```
 gentextpdf --text "BOOH" --angle wn --opacity 25
```

Comment: You could generate a template SVG with a substitution variable.  Substitute it on the fly and then pass it to inkscape's command line to build the PDF.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about transparency in a pdf, but perhaps your `multistamp` option does that for you. You can create a simple bit of PostScript with some grey text and then wrap that into a pdf eg:

```
#!/bin/bash
text=${1?missing text to show}
angle=45 # in degrees counterclockwise from horizontal
grey=0.75 # 0 is black 1 is white

ps2pdf - - <<!
%!PS
/cm { 28.4 mul } bind def
/draft-Bigfont /Helvetica-Bold findfont 72 scalefont def
/draft-copy { 
        gsave initgraphics $grey setgray 
        5 cm 10 cm moveto  
        $angle rotate 
        draft-Bigfont setfont
        ($text) show grestore
 } def
draft-copy showpage
!
```

This script takes as arg 1 your simple alphanumeric text. `ps2pdf` is part of ghostscript.

Comment: Usage: script.sh "TEXT" > out.pdf